# Get asset by extension or mime type?

Tags: templating, assets

Is it possible to query assets by it's filetype?

Example: I have a generic asset field, but I want to get the first asset that's an .mp4 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all .mp4 files:

```
{% set mp4s = craft.assets.filename('*.mp4').find() %}
```

To get the first .mp4:

```
{% set mp4 = craft.assets.filename('*.mp4').first() %}
```